# editing vb.net data connections and data sources

Tags: vb.net, dataset, datasource

I've inherited a VB.NET application that was developed against the production SQL-Server database. I now have a development SQL-Server and I want to make sure all the development work is done against the development copy of the data. Then deploy the application to production and have it run against the production SQL-Server.

I've added logic to my application so the startup of the first form checks to see whether it should run against the development or production server, then I can set the connection string and that's all working.

But there are several "Data Sources" defined, and they are using two different "data connections". I think I'd like to only have one data connection and have it point to the development copy of the data.

If my database has 50 tables and 5 forms, does this make sense to have only one "data connection", multiple data sources where some of the data sources have one 
data set and some of them have multiple data sets (they are nested)? Or am I thinking about these objects properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do either way, whatever you fancy. It all depends how you want to work, my system has 3 connections to different sources. Its nice to put it all in one place, but then you have the hassle of moving everything around. Having it split just means you need to know where it all is, and have correct naming conventions so you can identify exactly what you are connecting onto. So DataSource = "DevServerProduction1" or DataSource = "LiveServerProduction1". This will be on every table adapter.

I inherited a crap system which didn't even have a development environment, so I made a new connection to another dev server with a copy of live one and just changed the connection string to Dev connection, when I was ready to publish I just changed the connection string to Live connection.

Just make sure you backup the live programming files before you publish, just encase something goes wrong you can revert back.

Comment: Is there a way to rename an existing connection and have the new name update the TableAdapters? Or do I have to manually find the TableAdapters using that connection and edit them?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a comment but my score is high enough so I have to post here sorry about that.

Honestly it will kill you to change all your table adapters and duplicate them. You would have to not only change the adapter names but also all the code that connects onto it, the problem is when you inherit a system like mine or yours you find booby traps all over the place, and I am just getting round them all.

You need to go into Web.Config in the root of your source files. I have commented out the one I am not using, then simply when I am ready to publish I just comment the Development one and uncomment the live. There is an example below.

```
<connectionStrings>

<!--DEVELOPMENT MODE-->
'<add name="SameNameConnectionForBoth1" connectionString="Date Source=connectionDNSorIPforDev;initial catalog=YourDatabaseName1;integrated security=false;user id=UsernameHere;password=PasswordHere;connect timeout=90; providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
'<add name="SameNameConnectionForBoth2" connectionString="Data Source=connectionDNSorIPforDev;Initial Catalog=YourDatabasesName2;Integrated Security=True;Timeout=90;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<!--LIVE MODE-->
<add name="SameNameConnectionForBoth1" connectionString="Date Source=connectionDNSorIPforLive;initial catalog=YourDatabaseName1;integrated security=false;user id=UsernameHere;password=PasswordHere;connect timeout=90; providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="SameNameConnectionForBoth2" connectionString="Data Source=connectionDNSorIPforLive;Initial Catalog=YourDatabasesName2;Integrated Security=True;Timeout=90;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Only one or the other must be commented out for this to work. When you create a table adapter you choose the connection name of "SameNameConnectionForBoth1". Please note that there are 2 connection modes Live and Development Mode, and also 2 connections on each one if your table adapter needs to go to another connection you just name it "SameNameConnectionForBoth2". I don't know what you current system is and your might only need 1 connection. You will tailor the code above to your naming convention.

I hope this helps you.

If you need more help or details feel free to ask away.